# How to transform this Regex to not use Lookbehind?

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

I need to capture all lines starting with the `#` character in JavaScript. I tried using something like the following regex, but it turns out that JavaScript doesn't support positive lookbehind assertion `(?<=)`.

```
/(?<=\n)\#[^\n]*/g
```

How can I transform this regular expression into something supported by JavaScript?

Comment: does /^\#.*/ not work?

Comment: Your regex does not even say anything about `'#'`...

Comment: @Tomalak Corrected that.

Comment: @ChristianF It doesn't. It matches the first line if doesn't start with a `#`.

Comment: don't confuse [^\#] with ^\#. The former states a negation (don't match #), the second states that at the beginning (^) there should be a #. The "^" character has two meanings in regexs depending on the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
/^ *#(.*)$/m
```

And capture `match[1]` for text after `#`

Comment: I need to capture the whole line.

Comment: `match[0]` will give you whole line anyway.

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain the `$` and the trailing `m`? By the way, I need to capture *all*, and at best *only* all line matching the criteria.

Comment: `m` is for multiline that enables you to use `^` (line start) and `$` (line end) for each line in a multiline input.